# $scope not reflecting data in view, while $rootscope is reflecting?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am stuck with this from around one week. I am resolving my todo_id on "TodoDetailController", and then using a service to get todo details. But the controller is not working as expected. When I write a simple data on $scope its just not reflecting in my view, but the data in $rootscope is reflecting, But I don't want to use $rootscope everywhere.

Can someone please solve my query?

Here is the github project https://github.com/udayghulaxe/ticitic_todo

This is the project structure [image: todo app]

This is what I have done so far

```js
   

 /************* My states config ************************/
   

 .state('dashboard', {
       url: '/dashboard',
       abstract: true,
        views: {
                '': { templateUrl: './partials/main.html'},
                'header_toolbar@dashboard': { templateUrl: './views/header_toolbar.html' },
                'sidenavleft@dashboard': { templateUrl: './views/sidenav.html' },
                'widgets@dashboard': { templateUrl: './views/widgets.html'},
                'todo_detail@dashboard': { templateUrl: './views/todo_detail.html' }

              }
      })

      .state('dashboard.listdetail', {
       url: '/lists/:list_id/',
       templateUrl: './partials/list.detail.html',
       controller:'ListController',
       resolve: {
                   list_id: function($stateParams){
                       return $stateParams.list_id;
                   }
               },
       data: {
        authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.user],
        pageTitle: 'Lists'
       }
      })

      .state('dashboard.tododetail', {
      url: '/lists/:list_id/:todo_id',
      templateUrl: './partials/list.detail.html',
      controller:'TodoDetailController',
      resolve: {
              list_id: function($stateParams){
               //console.log($stateParams);
                  return $stateParams.list_id;
              },
              todo_id: function($stateParams){
               //console.log($stateParams);
                  return $stateParams.todo_id;
              }
          }
      })

/**************** My conrtoller *******************/

  

 app.controller("TodoDetailController",['$rootScope','$scope','$state', '$q', 'UserService', '$window','AuthService','DataService','AUTH_EVENTS','list_id','$mdSidenav','todo_id',
  function($rootScope,$scope, $state, $q, UserService, $window, AuthService, DataService,AUTH_EVENTS,list_id,$mdSidenav,todo_id)
{
  /********* This data is not relecting at all **********/
  $scope.list_id = list_id.toString();
  $scope.current_list =  UserService.GetTodoBylistid($rootScope.lists, $scope.list_id);
  $scope.value = 'Not refelcting in view';
  
  /**************** This is updating in view ***************************/
$rootScope.value2 = 'refelcting in view';

    $scope.$watch(todo_id, function() {
        $rootScope.todo_id = todo_id;
    }, true);
      toggleSidenav('right');
  };


}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject $rootscope after $scope like this

```
app.controller("TodoDetailController",['$scope','$state','$rootScope', '$q', 'UserService', '$window','AuthService','DataService','AUTH_EVENTS','list_id','$mdSidenav','todo_id',
  function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $q, UserService, $window, AuthService, DataService,AUTH_EVENTS,list_id,$mdSidenav,todo_id)
]);
```

Comment: Use  another name convention like $scope.listIds instead of using $scope.list_id . Check if it works.